# How to handle “Unable to receive message from renderer” in chrome driver?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Test Environment:

- chrome=73.0.3683.103
- chromedriver version: 73.0.3683.68
- java.version: '1.8.0_151'
- os.name: 'Windows 7'

I am getting following error:

```
Unable to receive message from renderer 
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 19.997 Timed out receiving message from renderer:-0.004
```

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Unable to receive message from renderer Timed out receiving message from renderer: 19.997 
Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.004
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Web Browsing Session** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *ChromeDriver* version is **73.0.3683.68**.
- Your *Chrome* version is **73.0.3683.103**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_151** which is pretty **old**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68*, *Chrome v73.0.3683.103* and *JDK v8u151*.

---

### Solution

Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u202**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: how do you know that ？how to check whether it is incompatibility or not ？

Comment: on the following site you can check version compatibility: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads