# Selenium gives "Timed out receiving message from renderer" for all websites after some execution time

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, renderer

I have an application where I need a long running instance of [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) web driver (I am using [Chrome driver 83.0.4103.39](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) in headless mode). Basically the app continuously pull url-data from a queue and gives the extracted url to Selenium which should perform some analysis on the website. Many of these websites could be down, unreachable or broken, so I've put a page load timeout of 10 seconds to avoid Selenium wait forever for page load. 
The problem I am having here is that after some execution time (let's say 10 minutes) Selenium starts to give `Timed out receiving message from renderer` error for every url. Initially it works properly, it correctly opens the good websites and goes on timeout on the bad ones (website fails to load), but after some time it starts to give timeout on everything, even websites that should open correctly (I've checked, they open correctly on Chrome browser).
I am having hard time to debug this problem, since every exception in the application is caught correctly. I have also noticed that this problem happens only in `headless` mode.

- UPDATE *
  During website analysis I also need to consider iframes (only top level), thus I've also added a logic to switch driver context to each iframe in the main page and extract the relative html.

This is a simplified version of the application:

```py
import traceback
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

width = 1024
height = 768

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-automation')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--force-device-scale-factor=1')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'window-size={width}x{height}')

chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US',
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.default_directory': '/dev/null',
        'automatic_downloads': 2,
        'download_restrictions': 3,
        'notifications': 2,
        'media_stream': 2,
        'media_stream_mic': 2,
        'media_stream_camera': 2,
        'durable_storage': 2,
    }
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)  # Timeout 10 seconds

# Polling queue
while True:
    url = queue.pop()

    # Try open url
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        continue

    # Take website screenshot
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()

    # Extract html from iframes (if any)
    htmls = [driver.page_source]
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")

    for index, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(index)
            htmls.append(driver.page_source)
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            continue

    # Do some analysis
    for html in htmls:
        # ...
        pass

    # Wait a bit
    sleep(0.1)
```

This is an example of stack trace:

```
Opening https://www.yourmechanic.com/user/appointment/3732777/?access_token=HLZYIg&ukey=6quWpg1724633&rcode=abttgi&utm_medium=sms&utm_source= rb
LOAD EXCEPTION Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbmacbookpro4ookpro4/Documents/Projects/python/proj001/main.py", line 202, in inference
    driver.get(url)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Has anyone any clue why after a while of correct execution Selenium starts to give timeout exception for any url it tries to open?

Comment: Error stack trace of _Timed out receiving message from renderer_

Comment: Added stack trace

Answer (score 12):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Deep Dive

This error can arise due to several reasons. A couple of those reasons and the remedy are as follows:

- `disable-infobars` and `--enable-automation` are almost *analogous* and `disable-infobars` is no more amaintained. `--enable-automation` will serve your purpose. So you need to drop:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Unable to hide “Chrome is being controlled by automated software” infobar within Chrome v76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298901/unable-to-hide-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-software-infobar-within/57317146#57317146)

- `--enable-automation` is still a `experimental_option` so you need to:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How can I use setExperimentalOption through Options using FirefoxDriver in Selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553189/how-can-i-use-setexperimentaloption-through-options-using-firefoxdriver-in-selen/62556837#62556837)

- If you intend to use `--enable-automation` you need to use `useAutomationExtension` as well:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  ```
- `--disable-gpu` is no longer necessary, so you need to drop:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Chrome Options in Python Selenium : Disable GPU vs Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724)

- You can opt use a bigger [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) through `{width}x{height}` e.g. `1920, 1080`

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)

- To initiate a [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) instead of `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` you need to use the `headless` attribute as follows:

  ```
  chrome_options.headless = True
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

- As you have [enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757917/how-to-use-webdriverwait-from-selenium-properly-through-python/62758328#62758328) all the [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) elements, it is worth to mention you can't `switch_to` all the `<iframe>` / `<frame>` as some of them may have the *style* attribute value set as **`display: none;`**.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable for element containing style=“display: none;”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848586/expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-element-to-be-clickable-for-element-conta/50852370#50852370)

- Finally, to *switch to* a [frame](/questions/tagged/frame) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired [`frame to be available and switch to it()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145944/how-to-extract-all-href-from-a-class-in-python-selenium/59146082#59146082) as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#whovaIframeSpeaker")))
  ```

> You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:
>
> - [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
> - [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [**Timed out receiving message from renderer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver) in:

- [Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630332/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000/59635244#59635244)
- [How to handle “Unable to receive message from renderer” in chrome driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765613/how-to-handle-unable-to-receive-message-from-renderer-in-chrome-driver/55767157#55767157)
- [Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017854/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer/52033769#52033769)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my question with a missing logic I was using to access iframes content (if any) on the website. I don't know if that can be related with the timeout problem though.

Comment: @revy Updated the answer with some of iframe related issues and solution. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my iframe logic to use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` instead of `switch_to.frame`. It has processed correctly 1000 urls or so then has started again to fail all the `get(url)` with timeout exception...
Anyway it must be something related to iframes because if I drop the iframe logic entirely the problem doesn't show up.

Comment: But unfortunately the problem still persist. I was able to process 1000 urls after the change but still it starts to fail with timeout for each url at some point (before the change it started to fail after 500-700 urls or so). I need the solution to be robust, even if it fails for some url to load it should continue to run correctly without interruption...I guess there is some race condition or so related to iframe switching that makes it start to fail forever with timeout, but I wasn't able to catch it so far.

Comment: Update: I've removed the iframes logic and run a test again. It has processed about 4500 urls than it has started again to throw timeout on everything...and finally hangs on the 4753 url (without any exception, just hang indefinitely). I don't know what else to try..