# Selenium scripts failing after chrome updated to 107

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, pom.xml

So my selenium scripts are getting stuck at driver.get ever since my chrome browser is updated to 107 . The scripts are running fine with browser 105 if I update the chrome script gets stuck at driver.get and gives the error unable to receive message from renderer.

I am using the latest 107 chromedriver , I have updated all the dependencies in pom.xml . Jdk version is 19 .

Comment: make a try with this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55767157/19611403]

Comment: I am using 107.0.5304.62 chrome driver and jdk 19.0.1 . Still the script is giving unable to receive message from renderer error